# Tornado secure cookie expiration (aka secure session cookie)

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

How can I set in Tornado a secure cookie that expires when the browser is closed?
If I use `set_cookie` I can do this without passing extra arguments (I just set the cookie), but how if I have to use `set_secure_cookie`?

I tried almost everything:

- passing nothing: expiration is set to its default value, that is 1 month
- passing an integer value: the value is considered as day, i.e. 1 means 1 day
- passing a float value: it works, for example setting 0.1 it means almost one hour and a half

Comment: They seem to have a similar interface and (apart from the encoded value) the same implementation. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried everything: calling set_secure_code without argument, with integer value, with float value (0.001, and it works BTW).

Comment: I suggest you add that to your question -- that way it's much easier to help you, and more people may be interested in helping someone who shows they have put in the effort, rather than just asking a question as soon as they're not sure what to do. Write down, in your question, what you tried, what you expected, and what the actual outcome was.

Comment: Thanks Linus, I appreciate your help and kindness.

Comment: Did you try passing `None`? What happens?

Comment: I feel shame, but It works. Thanks Linus. It was so simple, straightforward.

Comment: I'll post an answer, please accept it and we'll both profit! ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to me that you are really on the right track. You try lower and lower values, and the cookie has a lower and lower expiration time.

Pass `expires_days=None` to make it a session cookie (which expires when the browser is closed).

Comment: It's the simplest and most straightforward solution and, most important, it works.

Comment: I have set expires_days=None, but the cookie is not expiring when browser is closed. Can you please hint what might be going wrong. I am storing session in MemCache if its of any help

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this expires_days=None trick depends on browser bugs to work...